# How to change the color of a .xlsx cell with python if match condition, if not keep the old color

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, xlsx, pandas-styles

I first used pandas.style.background_gradient to make a gradient of all the the values in each row, but some values are nan, and the function put the backgroundcolor as black to those values. I tried to use something like this to change the value.

```
def black_to_white(val):
if is_nan(val) or isinstance(val, str): 
    color = 'white'
else: 
    color = same color
return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

but in the else stamente I dont know how to put the old color.

This is my code

```
dfs =df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',axis=1)
dfs = df.style.applymap(black_to_white)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I came up with an easy solution. I just added .

```
dfs =df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',axis=1).highlight_null('white')
```

And it works.